# How can i send mails daily using asp.net and smtp?

Tags: asp.net

I need to send mail daily using smtp and asp.net.

Comment: It seems a little unclear why you need to use asp.net. Maybe you want to be a bit more specific what your are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asp.net isn't the correct tool you should be using for sending automated daily emails.

The easiest route to go is to create a console application that is triggered through a windows scheduled task.

You could also just create a windows service that sends them at a specific time.

Comment: I would even suspect that the use case should be rather pulling information instead of pushing them (by e-mail).

Answer (score 1):

To send things on a schedule you need something other than just ASP.NET.  Scheduled tasks or Windows services (depending on your requirements) would allow running programs at a prescribed time or on a regular interval to do non-interactive processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window services. which is the best option to send daily email .

here you will find some needful information

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WIndows_Service.aspx